# Cordova App's localStorage wiped after AppStore update

Tags: database, cordova, persistence, storage, local

I need to save few datas on my App so i used localStorage. Actually LocalStorage is very useful: Free, fast and offline database.

But when I update my app from AppStore, all of my old datas gone. Localstorage wiped. Also when I search in stackoverflow, I learned that localStorage is reset when the memory of the device is full.

I'm looking for an easy to use, offline supported and permanent solution. I found pouchdb, but it's a bit complicated.

I'm curious about your suggestions.

Best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, LocalStorage will wipeout automatically, when you reinstall / update / memory full.

**Possible Solutions**

- You can use SQLite Plugin, If you want to store SQL based data
- Use Native Storage (https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage)
- Use Secure Storage (https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage)

Comment: I just checked Secure Storage. A bit complicated. For example i used earlier method like this : var x = localstorage.getitem('x'); How can i do this with Secure Storage?  This is the easist way to get data with S.Storage :

ss.get(function (value) { alert('Success, got ' + value); },function (error) { console.log('Error ' + error); },'mykey');

How can i assign this to variable?

Comment: Create a variable before calling secure storage, i mean outside the function; after a success callback, you can assign value to same variable; Example:  var x; ss.get(function(v) { x = v}, function(e) { console.log(e)} )

Comment: Thank you. Localstorage is synchronous but native storage is asynchronous. This is my main problem :(

Comment: But we don't have any other ways to do that :(

Comment: Is there no persistent and synchronous storage library?

Comment: As per my knowledge, these are best way to use; but I heard about https://github.com/localForage/localForage you can try that

Comment: Did anyone ever find a Persistent and synchronous solution?

Answer (score 1):

Right, you shouldn't rely on LocalStorage for anything important. I've used [Sqlite for Cordova](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) on a few projects and I think it works pretty well. The plugin provides a native implementation of Sqlite for your app to use. You get SQLite's features and the ability to run SQL queries, etc. The plugin persists the database to the device filesystem, so your data will be there after app updates. No affiliation, just a satisfied customer.

**Update:** OP clarified the requirements, and for storing a few simple key-value pairs you might consider the [Cordova Secure Storage plugin](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage). It works with iOS and Android and Windows 10, and is relatively straightforward to set up and use.

Comment: As you say, native SQLite is the only guaranteed persistent storage. In my empirical testing, an iOS device that's low on storage considers any data inside the Webview fair game for wiping: LocalStorage, WebSQL and IndexedDB can all get wiped.

Comment: I do not want to learn a huge library to store 2 datas in my app. I'm just storing (localStorage.language = en | fr)  and  (localStorage.sound = on | off). There should be a easy way.